# How to send JSON array to controller method that accept JArray

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, vb.net, json.net

I am trying to send JSON array to vb controller method that must accept JArray as param. All the times, on the dubug, the param method is null as if nothing was sent. Someone can help me?

JS/Jquery:

```
$("#id_build").change(function () {
$("#id_floor").empty();
var arr = new Array();
arr.push($("#id_build").val());
arr.push($("#id_build2").val());


$.get("/Home/Get/", JSON.stringify(arr), function (data) {

})
});
```

VB:

```
    <HttpGet>
    Function Get(jFloor As JArray) As JArray
        'Dim id As List(Of String) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of String))(jFloor)

        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

For now the return nothing in VB function it's ok.

Comment: It is unusual to use that kind of data in a GET. What does the query string look like if you do a network trace in the browser dev tools?

Comment: Look like this ?[%22value1%22,%22value2%22]

Comment: What happens if you try to accept a `String()` instead of `JArray` ?

Comment: jFloor always "Nothing"

Comment: If I create `var Obj = {"jFloor": arr}`, change `JArray` with `List(Of String)` and transorm it in a post request all works.

The problem is that i want receive a JArray, and I am not able to/ I can't send something compliant with the expected JArray.

Comment: Someone have some idea?

Comment: Maybe that kind of data is unusual for a get request but I need it to querying the database and return datas for an other get request

Comment: [Check this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2010247.aspx?Send+string+array+to+web+api). Your API will receive an array if you format the query string with multiple of the same variable name but different values.